# How to authenticate users using Lambda functions and AWS Cognito?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to authenticate users using a Lambda function written in Node.js in AWS. I'm stuck now. 
The following code doesn't work as expected:

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
      var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Password : 'password',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = { UserPoolId : 'My-Pool-Id',
        ClientId : 'My-Client-Id'
    };
    var userPool = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Pool : userPool
    };
    var cognitoUser = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('access token + ' + result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
           
            console.log('idToken + ' + result.idToken.jwtToken);
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },

    });

};
```

The code above is provided in [Cognito Documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html#using-amazon-cognito-identity-user-pools-javascript-example-authenticating-user)

But all I got is the following error:

```
TypeError: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails is not a function
```

Does anyone have some idea about what I should do now ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `AWSCognito` but that is not defined. Change it to `AWS`.

Are you trying to write a wrapper for cognito? You could do this authentication in the client instead of in a Lambda.

Comment: Hi @doorstuck, I've changed to AWS already but I got the same error. As for wrapper I'm not sure, I'm a newbie in this. All I did was to declare this "var AWS = require('aws-sdk');"in first line of code. I've just coded inline and didn't upload any file. Should I upload any library ?

Comment: @blackjack I was trying to figure out why you are writing this login code on the backend and not in the client. Normally I would write the code you have there in the client and then use the credentials you get from it to call other AWS resources. You can even use the credentials you get in the client to call API Gateway and authenticate the request. And that is build into API Gateway.

Can you update your code example with the change to `AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails`.

Comment: I'm affraid I've gone in the wrong way. I was trying to build a servless architecture with lambda to manage all user authentication and signup flows (sign in, reset passord, confirmation, and others). I'll change the code and give to client some responsibilities. I'll try to understand how AWS API Gateway will validate the client credentials.

Comment: @blackjack Here is how to use cognito with api gateway: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html.
So the client sends the JWT token (`idToken`) in the Authorization header and API Gateway will authorize the user. The user will then be found in `event.authorizer` in the lambda.
The client gets the JWT token by using code as you have above. Use the appropiate SDK for the client (javascript, android, ios, etc).

Comment: I'm gonna do it. Thanks